# Vue js method with argument and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout

I can't figure out why this code works..

```
data: {
    return {
        userMinerals: 0,
        mineralsLimit: 1000,
        miners: 0,
        superMiner: 0,
        minerPrice: 10,
        superMinerPrice: 100,
        minersLimit: 10
    }
}
methods: {
    counter() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.userMinerals += this.miners;

            if(this.checkLimit(this.userMinerals, this.mineralsLimit)) {
                this.userMinerals = this.mineralsLimit;
            }
        }, 100);
    },
    addMiner() {
        if (this.userMinerals >= this.minerPrice) {
            this.miners += 1;
            this.userMinerals -= this.minerPrice;
            this.counter();
        }
    }
}
```

.. but if I try to put parameters into counter() the code stops working

```
methods: {
    counter(typeOfCredits) {
        setInterval(() => {
            typeOfCredits += this.miners;

            if(this.checkLimit(this.userMinerals, this.mineralsLimit)) {
                typeOfCredits = this.mineralsLimit;
            }
        }, 100);
    },
    addMiner() {
        if (this.userMinerals >= this.minerPrice) {
            this.miners += 1;
            this.userMinerals -= this.minerPrice;
            this.counter(this.userMinerals);
        }
    }
}
```

From the console I can see that typeOfCredits gets incremented as it should but it doesn't update the value in the view.
Thx for help

Comment: The view has no reactive reference to `typeOfCredits`, I mean it's a simple variable, it's not a property of `data`.

Comment: `typeOfCredits` isn't a data property. You'd need to use `this.userMinerals` in the `counter` method

Comment: So I should use a data property as a function argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant reference a parameter and expect it to be changed outside, but you can pass a reference to an object that can change something outside.

```
var $this = this;
this.counter({
    get() { return $this.userMinerals },
    set(val) { $this.userMinerals = val }
});
```

and then use in the counter like this

```
    counter(typeOfCredits) {
        setInterval(() => {
            typeOfCredits.set(typeOfCredits.get() + this.miners);

            if(this.checkLimit(this.userMinerals, this.mineralsLimit)) {
                typeOfCredits.set(this.mineralsLimit);
            }
        }, 100);
    },
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5x8uzL5g/)

Answer (score 0):

`typeOfCredits` is a parameter to the function. Parameters are passed by value. Modifying it is like modifying a local variable.